# Deadlock when using await GetResponseAsync()

Tags: c#, json, wpf, asynchronous

I've successfully pulled json data into a string using a console application in visual studio 2015. Now I've tried to replicate this for wpf, but I've found I can't use .GetResponse() and I have to use GetResponseAsync() instead. After googling for a while I think I understand the point of async/await but I seem to be stuck in a deadlock. So here is my current code:

This is the async method that pulls the return data from a web API and returns a JSON string. Or in this case a `Task<String>`.

```
public async static Task<String> GetTrola(string station)
        {
            var url = "http://www.trola.si/" + station;

            string text;

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            var answer = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(answer.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return text;
        }
```

I then call the function in a button click event, like this:

```
string station = textBox.Text.ToString();
string output = GetJson.Trola.GetTrola(station).Result;
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(output);
```

But I think the problem is in the GetData function in particular this line:

```
var answer = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
```

I don't know why it happens, since i awaited the request with the `await` keyword? Something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line

```
string output = GetJson.Trola.GetTrola(station).Result;
```

you are blocking the UI thread. The same thread that the part of `GetData` after `await` needs to run on. Deadlock.

You should use `await` to get the result

```
string output = await GetJson.Trola.GetTrola(station);
```

You can find a very detailed explanation on [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Well I was trying that, but I guess I misread/misunderstood the error. Since I'm calling the method .getTrola in a button_click method that is void, I can't use the await operator in it. So I should write a new async method, and call it in the button_clicked method, right?

Comment: @mythic Make the event handler `async void`. Then you can use `await` inside. Normally `async` methods should return a `Task`, but in event handlers it's acceptable to use `async void`.

Answer (score 0):

I can refer [this](https://github.com/osoykan/DynamicTranslator/blob/master/src/DynamicTranslator/Orchestrators/Finders/TurengFinder.cs) code and repository for instance that exactly what you want.

```
public async Task<TranslateResult> Find(TranslateRequest translateRequest)
{
    if (!configuration.IsAppropriateForTranslation(TranslatorType))
        return new TranslateResult(false, new Maybe<string>());

    var address = configuration.TurengUrl;
    var uri = new Uri(address + translateRequest.CurrentText);

    var turenClient = new WebClient();
    turenClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    turenClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36");
    turenClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.6");
    turenClient.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpCacheAgeControl.MaxAge, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

    var compositeMean = await turenClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
    var organizer = meanOrganizerFactory.GetMeanOrganizers().First(x => x.TranslatorType == TranslatorType.TURENG);
    var mean = await organizer.OrganizeMean(compositeMean);

    return new TranslateResult(true, mean);
}
```